# Spring MVC Wrong UTF-8 encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, character-encoding

**Hello guys.** I created simple web app using Spring MVC and Hibernate, but I have weird problem with encoding. It's ok when I return .jsp view, or when I display info from MySQL database, but when I try to put new data by form with POST metod or when I want to display error message from Hibernate @Valid, then all letters like "ł,ą..." etc are replaced by some characters.

1. I tried to force response encoding:

   ```
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   ```
2. Add properties to session builder:

   ```
   private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
           Properties properties = new Properties();
           properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
           properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
           properties.put("charSet", "utf-8");


              return properties;
           }

           @Autowired
           @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
           public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
               LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
               sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
               sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(entity.User.class);
               return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
           }
   ```

3.Add Filter to servlet:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter;
        characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
```

4. Add tags in .jsp:

```
<% response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Extra info:
I use tomcat 7.0.76, and I didn't set up there anything, my database uses UTF-8 coding, same as my IDE. Whole project can be found on [GIT](https://github.com/Coneys/SpringMVCHibernate)

Also it is my first post on stackoverflow, so I just wanted to say hi. Hi! ;)